# How do I make main a friend of my class?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, friend

I'm thinking this is possible, but the compiler is complaining it cannot access the protected/private members of my class. I've tried moving stuff around and changing signatures, but can't find a combination that works.

I essentially have:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    friend int main(int argc, char** argv);

private:
    void test()
    {
        cout << "My friend has accessed my member" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyClass mc;
    mc.test();
}
```

Comment: Why is `test()` private in the first place?

Comment: @Blender: For `test`ing purposes? :P

Comment: What compiler.. works find in VS2010

Comment: Does declaring main before the definition of MyClass help?

Comment: In my case it doesn't, but I need to provide more info, this was an over simplification

Comment: Pls see my update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619356/how-do-i-make-main-a-friend-of-my-class-from-within-a-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is correct.

[Works in GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/BK8gx)

Comment: ok, yea it appears to work in 4.5.1 like that as well. I wasn't telling the whole story, trying to simplify...

Comment: Pls see my update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619356/how-do-i-make-main-a-friend-of-my-class-from-within-a-library

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't do what you're trying to do here -- there is certainly a better way.  That being said, you could try declaring the friend function in the global namespace, `friend int ::main` (note the use of the scope resolution operator `::`).

Comment: I tried this as well in my case, but didn't work. I need to provide more details to the problem...

Comment: Pls see my update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619356/how-do-i-make-main-a-friend-of-my-class-from-within-a-library